# Can co_yield return nothing?

Tags: c++, c++-coroutine

With the new C++ coroutines, is it possible to define a coroutine class that I can use to yield from functions without returning a value? Or does yield always have to return something? I'm just interested in the yielding functionality, not a yielded value.

I want this:

```
Coro Fn() {
   if (...) co_yield;

    co_return;
}
```

Not this:

```
Coro Fn() {
   if (...) co_yield dummyValue;

    co_return dymmyValue;
}
```

Comment: No.  This doesn't sound good, keep in mind that this code only runs when there is an iterator elsewhere in the program that consumes the yielded values.